# Group by year using Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to group by the year only in the created_at date field. I'm using postgres, and finding it different then from using Mysql.

I'm looking to display the years only and use them in a search parameter.

I'm getting the follow error: `missing attribute: created_at`

**Form for search**

```
<%= form_tag(page_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= select_tag :select_year, options_for_select(@years.map { |m| m.created_at.year }) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller (index)**

```
@trials = if params[:select_year]
  Product.where('extract(year from created_at) = ?', "#{params[:select_year]}")
  else
  Product.where('extract(year from created_at) = ?', Time.now.year))
  end

@years = Product.group('extract(year from created_at)').order('extract(year from created_at) DESC').select('extract(year from created_at)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `as` in your select,

```
.select('extract(year from created_at) AS created_at_year')
```

then you can call `@years.map(&:created_at_year)`

Comment: @DollarChills `@years.map` will iterate through each element , Isn't it bit ugly code, why don't you try this `@years_arrays = Product.order('extract(year from created_at) DESC').pluck('extract(year from created_at)')`

And in view 
`<%= select_tag :select_year, options_for_select(@years_arrays) %>` this will also enhance performance.

Answer (score 1):

Product#Index

```
def index
  #.....
  #Performance point of view
  @years_arrays = Product.order('extract(year from created_at) DESC').pluck('DISTINCT extract(year from created_at)')
end
```

view Search Form

```
<%= form_tag(page_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= select_tag :select_year, options_for_select(@years_arrays) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think you also might want to add `distinct` over the year values

Comment: distinct over pluck will raise `undefined method 'distinct' for Array`error. I edited the answer.

Comment: Added `DISTINCT` in pluck